# Converting map of sequence to map of vector

Tags: clojure

I've the following map in clojure:

```
{:filter [(:filter "f1\n") (:filter "f2\n")], :mangle [(:mangle "m1\n")]}
```

But for further processing I need sth. like:

```
{:filter ["f1\n" "f2\n"], :mangle ["m1\n"]}
```

How can I do this convertion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For problems like these, it is useful to have a utility function that can map across the values in a map:

- *Clojure Cookbook* defines a `map-values` on page 100.
- *Clojure Programming* defines a `map-map` on page 88, which preserves the map type.

With the following in place

```
(defn map-map [f m] (into (empty m) (for [[k v] m] [k (f v)])))
```

and given your map

```
(def m '{:filter [(:filter "f1\n") (:filter "f2\n")], :mangle [(:mangle "m1\n")]})
```

the problem boils down to mapping the `second` function across the elements in each value in your map:

```
(map-map #(mapv second %) m)
;=> {:filter ["f1\n" "f2\n"], :mangle ["m1\n"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
(def x '{:filter [(:filter "f1\n") (:filter "f2\n")], :mangle [(:mangle "m1\n")]})

(reduce-kv #(assoc %1 %2 (mapv second %3)) {} x)
;= {:mangle ["m1\n"], :filter ["f1\n" "f2\n"]}
```

Although it seems that you should be able to avoid the need for this processing step by just adding `"string"` to each vector instead of adding the whole list `(:key "string")`. That is of course, if you also own the function that generates the map.

Comment: Cool - works - now I've a look-upAndUnderstand job :-))
Many thanx ... you made my day :-)
Relating to your advice: The data producing function is not mine - so unfortunately I've no influence on the input data structure.